# Error messages in Javascript

Tags: java, jquery, html

So, I have two questions in my HTML code. After submitting the button, my code should display whether question # 1 and # 2 is correct right after the specified number. But the "msg" just prints on question # 1. How do I make the "msg" prints on both number? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankies!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>



function checkAnswers(){
    var retval = false;
    for(i=0;i<document.myForm.q.length;i++){
        if(document.myForm.q[i].value == "yes" && document.myForm.q[i].checked == true){
            retval = true;
        }
    }

        if(retval== true){
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Correct Answer!";
        }
        else if(retval == false){
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Wrong Answer!";
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" onsubmit="return checkAnswers(this)" name="myForm">
    <h1>QUESTIONS<h1>
    <h3>Question No. 1.) </h3> What is the world's number 1 shampoo?<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes" id="q"/>A. Hi</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="q"/>B. Hello</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="q"/>C. Ahh</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="q" />D. Kitkat</br>
    <span id="msg"></span>
    <br />
    <h3>Question No. 2.) </h3> What is the world's number 1 shampoo?<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no" id="q"/>A. Hi</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"  id="q"/>B. Hello</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  id="q"/>C. Ahh</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  id="q" />D. Kitkat</br>
    <span id="msg"></span>

    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">
    <br />
    <span id="score"></span><br />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My eyes bleed when I see js mixed with html and especially when it's in the head.

Comment: all the elements must have a unique id. instead of giving an id as id='msg', try giving a class like class='msg' and use document.getElementsByClassName('msg'). this is if you're not using jquery. in jquery you can simply use $('.msg').val('your message');

Comment: `checkAnswers` does not return anything

Comment: @Sushil i tried but it seems that the it prints the same msg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// i've edited your code a little and here it is. In your code, if you have choose the correct answer, and you change it, the "msg" doesn't change. it remains as "Correct answer!"    even though it is a wrong answer. But thanks for your help!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


function checkAnswers(){
    var retval = false;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){

        var inputName = inputs[i].getAttribute('name');            
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg-' + inputName);

        if(inputs[i].value == "yes" && inputs[i].checked == true){
            msg.innerHTML = 'Correct Answer!';      
        }
                else if(inputs[i].value == "yes" && inputs[i].checked != true){
                        msg.innerHTML = 'Wrong Answer!';
                }

    }
   return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return checkAnswers()">
    <h1>QUESTIONS</h1>
    <h3>Question No. 1.)</h3>What is the world's number 1 shampoo?
    <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes"  />A. Hi
    <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no" />B. Hello
    <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh
    <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat
    <br />
    <span id="msg-one"></span>
    <br />
    <h3>Question No. 2.)</h3>What is the world's number 1 shampoo?
    <br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi
    <br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello
    <br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh
    <br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat
    <br />
    <span id="msg-two"></span>
     <br/>
    <input type="button" name='submit' value="Submit"  />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[See this fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/dz3kradw/)

I changed your id="msg" to name="msg", look at the javascript below to see why! (And because it's not a good idea to have multiple element with the same id)

I removed id="q" because we can already get all radio without it !

```
<!-- No need to pass 'this' inside checkAnswers because we won't use it ! -->
<form action="#" onsubmit="return checkAnswers()" name="myForm">
     <h1>QUESTIONS<h1>
    <h3>Question No. 1.) </h3> What is the world's number 1 shampoo?<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes"/>A. Hi</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"/>B. Hello</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"/>C. Ahh</br>
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"/>D. Kitkat</br>
    <span name="msg"></span>
    <br />
    <h3>Question No. 2.) </h3> What is the world's number 1 shampoo?<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"/>A. Hi</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"/>B. Hello</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"/>C. Ahh</br>
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"/>D. Kitkat</br>
    <span name="msg"></span>

    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">
    <br />
    <span id="score"></span><br />
</form>
```

This is your js, We create a list of unique radio name, then check their value and show the result:

```
function checkAnswers() {
    var retval;

    //This gets all radio !
    var listRadio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

    //We need to loop only each group, not every radio
    //This array will hold all the unique names !
    var listNameRadioGroup = new Array();

    //We loop all radio, when the name is not in the array, we add it
    for (var i = 0; i < listRadio.length; i++) {
        if (listNameRadioGroup.indexOf(listRadio[i].name) === -1)
            listNameRadioGroup.push(listRadio[i].name);
    }

    //Then we only need to loop this new array to test each group
    for (i = 0; i < listNameRadioGroup.length; i++) {

        //We can access the value of the radio with .value on the element
        //listNameRadioGroup[i] will return the current name to test
        if (document.myForm[listNameRadioGroup[i]].value == "yes") {
            retval = true;
            //because msg is now a name, we can use getElementsByName and they will be in order !
            //So we set the value to correct
            document.getElementsByName("msg")[i].innerHTML = "Correct Answer!";
        }
        else {
            retval = false;
            document.getElementsByName("msg")[i].innerHTML = "Wrong Answer!";
        }

    }

    return retval;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In normal time you not put two time the same id but...your javascript/jquery need to look like that:

```
function checkAnswers(){
    var retval = false;
    for(i=0;i<document.myForm.q.length;i++){
        if(document.myForm.q[i].value == "yes" && document.myForm.q[i].checked == true){
            retval = true;
        }
       if(retval== true){
            $("span[id=msg]")[i].innerHTML="Correct Answer!";
        }
        else if(retval == false){
            $("span[id=msg]")[i].innerHTML="Wrong Answer!";
        }
    }
}
```

Because you need to loop all the msg span in your html and point at them.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns reference to a single element or `null`

Comment: @TamaraTrinity you're getting that error because you're not referencing jquery

Comment: @Sushil how do you access each msg[index] without using jquery?

Comment: instead of doing document.getElementsById('msg'), use document.getElementsByClassName('msg') and replace id='msg' in your html with class='msg' and then in your for loop just reference it by document.getElementsByClassName('msg')[index]

Comment: it would be easier if you can use jquery

Comment: does it work for u @TamaraTrinity? if yes then i can post it as an answer and you can mark it

Comment: @TamaraTrinity I've posted this as an answer. can you please mark it as an answer?